# where do i insert setTimeout() in the above script? since var id="#dialog"; is the div that is shown when the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, modal-dialog

```
$(document).ready(function() {  


    var id = "#dialog";

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    //transition effect     
    $('#mask').fadeIn('fast');  
    $('#mask').fadeTo('fast');  

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);
    //transition effect
    $(id).fadeIn('fast');   

//if close button is clicked
$('.window .close').click(function (e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mask').fadeOut();
    $('.window').fadeOut();
});     

//if mask is clicked
$('#mask').click(function () {
    $(this).unhide();
    $('.window').unhide();
}); 


});
```

Comment: can you describe what you want to do from this code?

Comment: this script automatically launches a modal dialog when the page is loaded..but my problem is i want to launch the modal dialog in a time(x) for example after 20seconds.

Comment: why don't you use jquery dialog and call .dialog("open") method in a function which can be call by setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

why do you need a setTimeout?  what are you trying to achieve?  A little more info is required if you would like a useful response.

add everything you have in your $(document).ready to another function say showDialog() .
then in $(doc).ready add:

var myTimeout = setTimeout(showDialog,20000);

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
$(document).ready( function(){

  (function delayedModal(){
    var id = '#dialog';
    // ...snip...
    var timer = setTimeout( function(){ 
       $(id).fadeIn('fast');
    },20000);
  }());

  // ...snip...

});
```